# Function for read and write file in phonegap @ cordova

Tags: file, cordova, file-io

I need a function to read and write file in phonegap.

Ex:

```
function isTextFileEmpty(fileName){
   //this function should return weather the file is empty or not. If file empty then return true... if file is not empty then return false    
}

function getTextFileContent(fileName){
    //this function should return content of the file
}

function writeTextFile(fileName, textContent){
    //this function should write given text in the file
}
```

The `www/` folder will have `userinfo.txt`
When user will open the app I need to check is the userinfo.txt is empty or not. Suppose its empty then I will ask pin number... so user will enter pin number... so that time I will store the pin number in in the text file. So next time onwards I will check is the file is empty if its not empty... then I will get the pin number from the file and will use it to get data from server via JSON

Comment: Did you succeed? Will be nice to finally see the answer

Comment: @Qvatra I used Database to solve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant Cordova docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I already read the 2.7.0 document... i couldn't make it as function so I am expecting if someone help me..

Comment: What did you try?  All you showed was skeleton code.  Further, I don't think you can (at least on iOS) modify files in www.